# Pegasus 20-kg travel allowance: one bag or multiple bags?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, pegasus-airlines

The Pegasus Airlines ["Essentials" package](https://www.flypgs.com/en/travel-services/other-travel-services/flight-packages#essentials) (**edit:** for an International flight) includes 20 kg of checked baggage. But the web page doesn't say whether that's in a single piece of luggage or multiple items. I *think* they mean multiple items, since you can purchase extra baggage in terms of weight rather than items, but I'm not sure.

So, which is it? Please only answer from personal experience or if you've seen this stated explicitly.

I tried contacting them through the website but am hitting a circular redirection loop...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just called Pegasus Call Center (*+90 888 228 1212*) in Turkey. They said that there is no limit for the number of bags. Since your baggage allowance is 20-kg due to the "Essentials Package", your flight must be international. The reply of the call center was for international flights as well.

Comment: This is generally true for any flight using Weight Concept for baggage allowance.

Comment: Would have +2'ed you for going to the extra effort of making a call on my behalf...

Answer (score 6):

Although the [Pegasus Conditions of Carriage](https://www.flypgs.com/en/useful-info/info-about-flights/general-rules#2087) specify

> 9.3.1.  For all Pegasus flights our passengers will have a limited Checked Baggage allowance in terms of the number of pieces, weight and dimensions of their baggage, identified in accordance with the Package based on which their Ticket is issued.

in fact, nowhere is any limit on pieces specified. Indeed, if there were such a limit, Pegasus would surely impose a surcharge for exceeding the limit, but all such [excess baggage fees](https://cdnp.flypgs.com/files/pdf/Bagaj_Ucretleri_Genel_Kurallar_01_06_2018_Total_EN.pdf) are based solely on weight.

Broadly speaking, a flight with checked baggage limits set according to the *[weight concept](http://traveltips.usatoday.com/much-weight-can-pack-plane-109157.html)* does not impose a maximum number of individual bags. Theoretically, you could check 10 bags each weighing 2 Kg if you preferred. The airline may enforce a maximum weight or dimensions for any individual bag, of course.

(Weight concept remains the norm in most of the world; *piece concept*, where a fixed limit is set per bag and then a limit set on the number of bags, was used primarily to/from or within North America, although several major non-North American airlines have adopted it for all their routes in recent years.)